# Adding or deleting data in a file with Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

my idea is to be able to edit files in storage.
This edition consists of adding or deleting file data according to the firebase trigger.

I created a trigger in firebase after obtaining the file with the bucket.file `function ("file.txt"). CreateReadStream ()`
and I edited the data in the base in the change in the firebase after this I updated the file with the function
b`ucket.file ("file.txt"). createWriteStream ()`.
This solution is good when there is 1 trigger, but when there are more than 2 triggers, the data does not keep correctly why the file is overwritten with the data it had before.

Example

this is the content of file.txt

> This text is an example

and executed 2 triggers
the 2 activators get the file at the same time and the first trigger adds data and overwrites the file with this message

> this text is an example
>
> and this file was edited with the first trigger

and the second activator erases data and overwrites the file with this message

> this text

When the triggers are finished, the file has "this text"
but this file must have

> this text
>
> and this file was edited with the first trigger

Someone help me.

```
exports.createData = functions.database.ref('data/{id}/summary/status').onCreate((data, context) => {
    let status = data._data;
    return Promise.all([ admin.database().ref('data/' + context.params.id + '/summary/entityUrl').once('value', (snapshot) => {
        let entityUrl = snapshot.val(); 
        if (isDataValid(status))
            return  addDataFile(entityUrl) ;
        return; 
    }) ]);  
})
function addDataFile(entityUrl){
    return Promise.all([ returnFile("txt",() => {
        dataFile.splice(dataFile.length - 1, 0, `new data ${entityUrl}`)
        updateFileStorage("txt", dataFile.join('\n'));  
    }) ]);
    
}
function returnFile(extension, callback) {
    let respData = "";
    if (dataFile == null ){
        return bucket.file(FileUrl + extension).createReadStream()
            .on('data', (chunk) => {
                respData += chunk;
            })
            .on('end', () => {
                dataFile = respData.split('\n');
                callback();
            })
            .on('error', (error) => {
                console.log("Error en lectura")
                return returnFile(extension, callback);
            })
    }
    else callback();
    return;
}
function updateFileStorage(extension,data, trys ){
    trys = typeof trys !== 'undefined' ? trys : 0;
    if(trys>6)
        return;
    var s = new Readable();
    s._read = function noop() { };
    s.push(data);
    s.push(null);
    return s.pipe(bucket.file(FileUrl + extension).createWriteStream())
        .on('finish', function () {
            //console.log("File updated");
            return;
        })
        .on('error', function (err) {
            console.log("Error de Escritura");
            return setTimeout(() => {
                return updateFileStorage(extension, data, trys + 1)
            }, 250);
        })
}
```

Comment: You should add to your post the full code of your Cloud Function. It is very difficult to understand what you exactly do, for the moment.

Comment: i added the code

Comment: There are several places in your code which need to be modified, in particular in terms of how to deal with promises. I would suggest you watch these three videos from the Firebase team: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IkUgCLr5oA&t=27s and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=652XeeKNHSk and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d9GrysWH1Lc&t=302s. You will notice that in your case you don't need to use promise.all I think. Also have look at the Cloud Functions samples, a great way to study how code is organised: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples. I hope this helps.

Comment: These videos help me to refactor my code but my problem is the same. Is there a way to make the file concurrent with cloud functions?